# Fallo al Iterar en REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

*Hola a todos* tengo este fallo. Cuando intento iterar( y los datos llegan, esta comprobado) me dice que **.map no es una funcion**:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
// Importar cliente Axios
import clienteAxios from '../../config/axios';


function Clientes () {
    // Trabajar con el State
    // clientes = State
    // guardarClientes = Funcion para guardar el State
    const [clientes, guardarClientes] = useState({});
    //Query a la API
    const consultarAPI = async() => {
        // console.log('Consultando...');
        const clientesConsulta = await clienteAxios.get('/clientes');
        // console.log(clientesConsulta.data);

        // Colocar el resultado en el State
        guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data);
    }

    //  Use effect es similar a componentdidmount y willmount
    useEffect( () => {
        consultarAPI();
    }, [] );

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Clientes</h2>
            {console.log(clientes)}
            {/* {console.log(guardarClientes)} */}

            {/* <ul className="listado-clientes">
                {clientes.map(cliente => {
                   console.log(cliente);
                })} 
            </ul> */}
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Clientes;
```

Al hacer **console.log** de  clientesConsulta.data me da :

```
{clientes: Array(5)}
  clientes: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  __proto__: Object
```

Vamos que los datos llegan, podria ser tambiien clientesConsulta.data.clientes y da:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

El caso es que no itera conninguna de las 2. Y en las 2 los datos llegan de la API correctamente.

Me he quuedado sin ideas, muchas gracias de antemano

**Edicion para user177767**

```
function createArray(clientes) {
        if (clientes && clientes.length > 0) {
          return clientes.map(cliente => console.log(cliente)
          );
        }
        return [];
      }




    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Clientes</h2>
            {/* {console.log(clientes)} */}
            {/* {console.log(guardarClientes)} */}

            <ul className="listado-clientes">
                {createArray(clientes)}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Algo asi? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro, hace bastante que no me pongo con React, prueba a tratar ese for en una función aparte o antes del return de manera que pintes/devuelvas el html que necesitas.

Algo como esto:

```
function createArray(array) {
  if (array && array.length > 0) {
    return array.map(element => `${element.name}<${element.email}>`);
  }
  return [];
}
```

...

Y lo llamas con createArray(cliente) donde lo quieres pintar

Un saludo,

Comment: Muuchas gracias por la respuesta user177767. Lo estoy probando creo que he cogido la idea. Una vez mas mil gracias :))))

Comment: user177767. He puesto ese codigo y funciona pero no da los datos en consola.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a **user177767** por su magisterio. **Su intuición ha sido la correcta**.

```
function createArray(clientes) {
        if (clientes && clientes.length > 0) {
          return clientes.map(cliente => console.log(cliente)
          );
        }
        return [];
      }




    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Clientes</h2>
            {/* {console.log(clientes)} */}
            {/* {console.log(guardarClientes)} */}

            <ul className="listado-clientes">
                {createArray(clientes)}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
```

Ademas `guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);`
No como estaba antes `guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data);`

Y asi funciona bien, da el resultado dos veces pero eso es aparte de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const [clientes, guardarClientes] = useState({});
```

El valor inicial de clientes, antes de que realices la consulta con Axios, es un objeto vacio, lo que significa que durante el primer render de tu componente estas intentando hacer un `.map` sobre un objeto.

Para solucionarlo deberia bastarte con cambiar el estado inicial a un arreglo vacio de la siguiente manera

```
    const [clientes, guardarClientes] = useState([]);
```

No es necesario que uses una funcion, de hecho es menos eficiente

Comment: Hola Gerardo, lo he estado probando pero insiste. no obstante tuu apunte esta muy bien y no lo habia tenido en cuenta. Hoy es mi 3 dia con React y voy muy torpe. Ademas he avanzado un poco el proyecto en este rato y a la hora de mostrar en la pagina no sale doble. Pero bueno sigo mirandolo hay que buscar la mejor forma de hacerlo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda